# Can I assign a variable to a variable which is assigned to a Class instances? - Python Question

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a text-based game and I've been having this problem that I don't know how to solve...

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, hp, maxHp, attack, defense):
        self.maxHp = 100
        self.hp = self.maxHp
        self.attack = 5
        self.defense = 1
# --- Now we just create the two different enemies from this class --- #
tutoEnemy1 = Enemy(100, 100, 5, 1)
tutoEnemy2 = Enemy(100, 100, 5, 1)
```

Here is the code involved with the problem. I assigned two variables to the Class instances to obtain two separate enemies. One called tutoEnemy1 and other called tutoEnemy2

In the code of the game, the section which contains the fight functions of course has one which involves attacking the enemy. I originally thought that by creating two separate 'if' statements, the moment in which you select the enemy you'd like to attack everything would go ok but then I realised that in the moment that more than 2 enemies appeared I had lots of garbage, repeated code involving the process of calculating the damage and all that stuff.

I came with an idea that consisted on defining a function which realized the damage calculation process everytime, that way I didn't had to repeat any code

```
def damage():
    option = input("> ")
    if option == 1:
        selectedEnemy = tutoEnemy1()
    elif option == 2:
        selectedEnemy = tutoEnemy2()
    else:
        input("Incorrect input, type a correct one.")
        damage()
    rawDamage = Player.attack * multiplierDamage
    finalDamage = rawDamage - selectedEnemy.defense
    selectedEnemy -= finalDamage
```

The problem comes that originally I assigned the Enemy class instances to the "tutoEnemy1&2" variables and everything worked fine. But now, it gives me the problem that the variable of "selectedEnemy" doesn't seem to work the way I intended (taking the info of one enemy or the other).It just gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\acmem\Desktop\Text-Based Game\RPG.py", line 75, in <module>
    selectedEnemy = tutoEnemy1()
TypeError: 'Enemy' object is not callable
```

Is there a way to do so? If so, what is the correct sintax? (I work with Python 3.0)

Comment: You don't need the parentheses on the end.  Just use `selectedEnemy = tutoEnemy1`

Answer (score 1):

To assign a reference of either tutoEnemy1 or tutoEnemy2 to 'selectedEnemy' you should drop the brackets, as they are the standard syntax of calling a function.
As tutoEnemy1 and tutoEnemy2 are not callable (=not functions), this error is thrown.

So the code should look like this:

```py
def damage():
    option = input("> ")
    if option == 1:
        selectedEnemy = tutoEnemy1
    elif option == 2:
        selectedEnemy = tutoEnemy2
```

You may get a problem with your last statement though, as you try to subtract the damage from the selectedEnemy instance and not from their HP, so you probably want something like this:

```py
    selectedEnemy.hp -= finalDamage
```